# Bizarre behaviour of some of my code using strftime()

Tags: php, time

I'm pulling some dates from a DB and using PHP `strftime` to format them.

Now, everything works as intended, apart that if I use the `%A` format, which is supposed to give me the full weekday name the function just returns NULL, unless the date happens to be on a weekend, in which case it correctly returns "Saturday" or "Sunday".

All the other formats work, even `%a` (short weekday name).
It does not seem to depend on the locale I use, nor on the specific format of the date (same problem happens if I just use `strftime` on `mktime`.

My only thought is that it's some sort of incredibly weird configuration problem server side, but I'd like to hear if anyone had other ideas about it...

EDIT: some code, although it's pretty much what I have written before...

```
$id = (int)$_GET['event'];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT date FROM events WHERE event_id=".$id);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

echo strftime("%a %H:%M", $row['date']);
echo strftime("%A %H:%M", $row['date']);
```

The first echo works fine, returning for instance `Thu 15:30`, the second returns NULL unless `$row['date']` falls on a Saturday or Sunday.

If this may be of any help the code is inside a class, but I can't see how this may affect the result...

EDIT2: This is **NOT** a problem with the DB or the date format, otherwise the first echo wouldn't work. Also, I can just remove the DB code, and generate the date with `mktime` or with `strtotime` and it still doesn't work.

EDIT3 (solution): Found the issue. In Italian, the names of the days end in ì (e.g. lunedì), apart from Saturday and Sunday, which do not have accented letters. The result of the operation was passed to `json_encode` which apparently doesn't like accented characters... A call to `utf8_encode` (or to `htmlentities`) solved the issue.

Comment: you really should be posting the code and the failing timestamp here.

Comment: if they are in a date field uses the db to format them if mysql: DATE_FORMAT()

Comment: Without posting the code that isn't working, all anyone could do is guess.

Comment: @Dagon: I'm using different formats depending on how far in time the date is, so it may be tricky to do it on the DB. Also can I use different locales when querying mysql?

Comment: it's not a code to help anything. We cannot guess $row['date'] **actual** value, can we? You're having issues with strftime, so, post strftime testing code, not SQL queries.

Comment: @nico, you missed the data in the db. Can you post a date column that works for you and one that doesn't work?

Comment: question: why don't you use date(), or eaven better datetime class ? you could try both and see if you get the desired output.

Comment: @poelinca: because `date()` is not locale-aware. I'm not sure about the `datetime` class, I'll have a look into that, thanks.

Comment: @JohnP, @Col.: it's not a problem in the DB, see my new edit. Anyway the dates in the DB are just standard dates, such as `2011-04-06 08:33:29`.

Comment: @nico, could you run [example number four on the `strftime` manual page](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#example-637) and provide the output in your question?  strftime relies on the underlying C library to provide formatting, so perhaps it's a problem with the underlying server instead of PHP itself.

Comment: @nico, that might be the case. I asked for the dates so I could run the code on my pc and verify the issue :)

Comment: @Col.: thank you for your comment, but nobody forces you to answer, so if you think my question is not up to your standard just press the X on the top-right of your browser window, that should solve the issue.

Comment: Well, I'd rather press flag button next to the question.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel : what's with the flag? This question is not spam, it does belong here, and although it might not be up standards, I doubt that this is the worst accepted question on SO. You have votes to express your disagreement.

Comment: @Joris may be it's not worst one but still it's unacceptable and deserves the flag. it's not "disagreement" as you call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

If you're passing something other than a timestamp you're doing it wrong. Can't really say why the first one passes and the second one doesn't. Maybe PHP is trying to compensate. In any case, if you have a text time representation, you need to call `strtotime()` on it first.

**EDIT**

I ran the following code in my system

```
$row['date'] = '2011-04-06 08:33:29';
echo strftime("%a %H:%M", $row['date']);
echo '<br>';
echo strftime("%A %H:%M", $row['date']);
```

And I got this as the output

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in F:\webroot\utils\test.php on line 4
Thu 00:33

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in F:\webroot\utils\test.php on line 6
Thursday 00:33
```

You should have notices enabled on your system. Changing it to timestamp should solve it.

**EDIT 2**

> ...Also, I can just remove the DB code,
>   and generate the date with mktime or
>   with strtotime and it still doesn't
>   work

If you could post the sample that doesn't work we could have a look

Comment: and why would Saturday and Sundays work? PS: `strtotime` doesn't solve the problem unfortunately... but thanks anyway for pointing out the wrong argument. (PS: I don't get any notice and I do have error reporting on)

Comment: I just have `error_reporting  =  E_ALL`. You might have notices turned off. You mentioned you do some locale modification before you run the strftime(), that might be providing you some sane defaults. Try posting the `strtotime()` calls you made (with the data) so we can have a look

Comment: OK... I seem to have tackled down the issue, although I still can't find the problem. If I take the code and put it outside of the class it works perfectly, if instead I leave it in the class it doesn't work... I'll do some more tests and post an update when I have something more concrete. Thanks a lot for trying to help.

Comment: Well, part of the error was the date format. Now it works if I keep English as a locale. When I put an Italian locale, however, I go back to the old problem. I'll mark your answer as accepted, and try to find what the specific problem is. Thanks for taking time to answer.

Comment: I think since strtotime expects a us english time format, maybe your localization is messing it up. Have a look at the data just before it goes to the method. Glad to help :)

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem (e.g. issues with date as day/month/year or year/month/date etc.). I'll try to sort that out tonight.

Comment: Found the issue. In Italian, the names of the days end in `ì` (e.g. lunedì), apart from Saturday and Sunday. The result of the operation was passed to `json_encode` which apparently doesn't like accented characters... A call to `htmlentities` solved the issue.

Comment: You might want to post that bit as an answer. It will help anyone who comes along with the same problem :)

Answer (score 3):

In your comments you say that your database contains dates such as `2011-04-06 08:33:29`. But the second argument to `strftime` should be a unix timestamp such as `1302766547`, that is the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT`. Try this instead:

```
echo strftime('%a %H:%M', strtotime($row['date']));
```

Comment: and why would Saturday and Sundays work? PS: strtotime doesn't solve the problem unfortunately... but thanks anyway for pointing out the wrong argument.

Comment: Well, it's undefined behaviour. It could format your hard drive and still be according to spec. It wouldn't be very nice, but it would not be against the spec :-)

Comment: fine for me, I'm not the owner of the server! :P